# Json Parsing error in rootarray "listProfile"

Tags: swift3

I m getting error when I m trying to Parse. Here is my code I want both the values stored in user defaults. How can this problem be solved?

```
 func loaddata()
   {

    let id1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Userid")
    let usertype1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "usertype1")
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/donorprofile.php?donorid=\(id1 ?? "")&usertype=\(usertype1 ?? "")")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {(data : Data?, response : URLResponse?,error : Error?) in

    if error == nil
    {
        print("unable to fetch")

    }

    do
    {
        let rootdictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

        var rootarray = rootdictionary.object(forKey: "listDonorprofile") as! NSArray

        for item in rootarray
        {

            let obj = item as! NSDictionary                
            self.temp.name = obj.object(forKey: "Nameofdonor") as? String ?? ""

            self.temp.donarid = obj.object(forKey: "DonorID") as? String ?? ""
            self.temp.gender = obj.object(forKey: "Gender") as? String ?? ""
            self.temp.emailid = obj.object(forKey: "EmailID") as? String ?? ""
            self.temp.mobno = obj.object(forKey: "MobileNo") as? String ?? ""
            self.temp.country = obj.object(forKey: "Country") as? String ?? ""

            self.arrayuser.append(self.temp)



      }

    }
}
task.resume()
}

}
```

Comment: In which line are u facing error and post your error message.

Comment: Add crash log or error in question.

Comment: in var rootarray line program crashes

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I m not getting the problem why it is crashing at that point I have implemented this previously but onlt with one user defined value

Comment: I want to know is anything wrong while writing the code can u please check nd tel

Comment: thank you there was no error my url was going wrong

Comment: but i have fetched the hard coded user if dynamically i want to fetch two default values how do i provide it in url can you help in it.

Comment: now i have given like this "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/donorprofile.php?donorid=1&usertype=Individual"

Comment: but i want it to be like ths"http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/donorprofile.php?donorid=\(id1)&usertype=\(UserType)"